# How to spread dried blueberries evenly when using bread machine?

Tags: bread, dough, mixing, blueberries

This [blueberry oatmeal bread recipe](https://www.bigoven.com/recipe/blueberry-oatmeal-bread/2291289) says to add 2/3 cup dried blueberries to the bread machine at add-in time. When I just dump them in on top of the dough, they end up clustered at the bottom of the loaf, as shown:

[image: right-side-up loaf]
[image: loaf turned on its side]

(How) can I get them to be evenly distributed?

**Update**

As bob1 suggested, I tried adding the dried blueberries at the very start. That worked. The blueberries were evenly distributed and none the worse for the earlier inclusion.

[image: bread with distributed blueberries]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them at the start of the mixing process to help distribute them evenly. You may find that soaking them for a few minutes in warm water to re-hydrate will help the berries mix more evenly if adding at the add-in-time.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [U.S. Highbush Blueberry Council](https://www.blueberrycouncil.org/blueberry-cooking-tips/baking-blueberries/), you can spread half the batter, add the berries, and top with the second half of the batter. But, I usually coat the blueberries in flour. It prevents them from sinking and from "bleeding blueberry juice" into your loaf. That's what works for me.

Comment: Dies the floor make any difference for dried berries? I know the trick for raw or frozen ones.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems more suited to batter than to dough made in a bread machine.

Comment: Try the floured berry trick, Ellen. It may help suspend them in the batter - even in a bread machine. (I will confess that I don't own a bread machine, so no way for me to test it by that method.)